# Dynamically set default date on primefaces calendar with javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I need to set a suggested date for a `p:calendar` given the selected date in another calendar. I can get a string representation by the date to set by parsing the DOM, so no problems there. I try to use the *Client Side API* for the component, because the preferred way is to do this as the calendar is selected:

**The Client Side API method** (as described in the primefaces documentation):

> *setDate(date):* Date to display (Sets display date)

**The calendar component:**

```
<p:calendar value="#{someVar.startDate}"
            locale="en_GB"
            navigator="true"
            id="startDate"
            showOtherMonths="true"
            size="11"
            pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"
            pages="4"
            widgetVar="startDateCalendar"
            onclick="startDateCalendar.setDate(new Date(2012, 9, 9));"/>
```

This does not affect anything, even though the function is being executed. I have debugged that.

Is it possible to use javascript to set a default date for `p:calendar`? Ideally, it should work as the `pagedate` attribute for the component, i.e. it is only a suggested date pre-filled for the calendar, not pre-fill an actual value.

Answer (score -1):

Set the default date in your bean.

```
private Date date = new Date(); // define your start date here

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public Date setDate(final Date newDate) {
    this.date = newDate;
}
```

Comment: OP clearly wrote that he want to do this in PrimeFaces Client Side API (JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks. But there is a reason we don't want to do that. It would require plenty and ugly logic. It's not just the matter of a default value, it is a whole tree of calendars we would need to parse to get the right one. Using javascript this could be done with a lot less code.

Comment: The logic needs to somewhere, right? Why would you need to parse anything? If you have a Date object for every calendar (do you?), the value of the calendar component should be in the bean. Therefore the value for each calendar can easily defined in the Java code.

Comment: Believe me. We are using a `p:treeTable` with up to 200 calendar inputs. It would require parsing down that datastructure and find the correct date. Then use some jQuery like syntax to re-render the correct row.

Comment: @Magnilex: No it would not, the component would (almost) automagically do that. You most like have some other 'workaround' already that requires this additional way of setting a value

Answer (score -1):

Try `onclick="PF('calendar_widget_name').setDate(new Date(2012, 9, 9));"`

Comment: For the version the OP used, using `PF('...') was not needed (yet). OP stated that the function was called, he debugged it!.